# I have this error while trying to map in flutter

Tags: flutter, api

I want to get data from API and I tried the link in postman and its working here it is:
[
{
"Id": "14",
"title": "Facebook vs instagram?",
},
{
"Id": "15",
"title": "Facebook vs instagram?",
},
{
"Id": "16",
"title": "Facebook vs instagram?",
},
]

but when I am trying to do a map this error appears :
The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'

Here is my code :
This error appears in this file and print(recieved) print the same data as postman but the problem in map
httpservice.dart:
`

```
class HttpService {
  final String postsURL =
      "";

  Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(postsURL));

    request.fields.addAll(
      {
        'post_type': "read_user",
        'uid': "27",
      },
    );

    var headers = {
      'token': "aaa",
      'lang': "lang",
    };

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    List<Post> Posts = [];
    try {
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String received = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        print(received); 

        List<Post> posts = received
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();

        return Posts;
      } else {
        print("error response $response.statusCode");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error catch $e");
    }
    return Posts;
  }
}
```

`

post_model.dart :

`

```
class Post {
  final String Id;
  final String title;

  Post({
    required this.Id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
       Id: json['Id'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

`
post.dart :

```
class PostsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final HttpService httpService = HttpService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Posts"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: httpService.getPosts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Post> posts = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView(
              children: posts
                  .map(
                    (Post post) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(post.title),
                      subtitle: Text("${post.Id}"),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these in your `HttpService()`:

```
 try {
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String received = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        print(received); 

        List<Post> posts = received
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();

        return Posts;
      } else {
        print("error response $response.statusCode");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error catch $e");
    }
```

with these :

```
try {
  http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse = await request.send();
  if (streamedResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

    List<Post> posts = received
        .map(
          (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
        )
        .toList();

    return posts;
  }else {
    print("error response ${streamedResponse.statusCode}");
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("error catch $e");
}
```

Comment: The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'StreamedResponse'.
Try importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named : this error appears

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @sam